# Server side event handlers not firing when postback button is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, firefox

I'm trying to prevent duplicate form post by disabling the button using jquery and hooking into on click handler for button. All works very well in IE but in FireFox the issue I'm having is that none of my server side event handlers are firing during post back, using IE I can hit debug stop points in event handlers and step through but firefox only page load fires and none of event handler code is firing. Anyone else seen this?, my server environment is running windows server 2012 OS

Comment: can i show your sample code

Comment: I think you meant "can I see sample code" its pretty straight forward, disable button and PostBack to server, as I mentioned in thread it works in IE, I even tested in Safari, Chrome no issues, FireFox not so much, really bizzare

Comment: have you checked the console in firefox for any errors. Page load is server side so assume that the when you hit debug you are debugging server side. Some code would be helpful.

Comment: give me a few I will set up a demo page and share a link